# Calcular diferencias entre filas en base a distintas referencias

Tags: r

Tengo este dataset

| id | unico | saldo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 100 |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 90 |
| aa | aa_yy_bb | 300 |
| aa | aa_yy_bb | 200 |
| aa | aa_qq_cc | 85 |
| aa | aa_qq_cc | 60 |

```
  filter(unico == id_aa_xx_zz) %>% 
  mutate(dif_saldo = -c(diff(saldo),NA))
```

y obtengo el siguiente df

| id | unico | saldo | dif_saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 100 | 10 |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 90 | NA |

Pero ¿qué debo hacer para obtener este, si no quiero estar filtrando por cada `unico`?

| id | unico | saldo | dif_saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 100 | 10 |
| aa | aa_xx_zz | 90 | NA |
| aa | aa_yy_bb | 300 | 100 |
| aa | aa_yy_bb | 200 | NA |
| aa | aa_qq_cc | 85 | 25 |
| aa | aa_qq_cc | 60 | NA |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar el verbo `group_by()` para condicionar el `mutate` a grupos que definas:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, unico) %>% 
  mutate(dif_saldo = -c(diff(saldo),NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id, unico [3]
  id    unico    saldo dif_saldo
  <chr> <chr>    <int>     <int>
1 aa    aa_xx_zz   100        10
2 aa    aa_xx_zz    90        NA
3 aa    aa_yy_bb   300       100
4 aa    aa_yy_bb   200        NA
5 aa    aa_qq_cc    85        25
6 aa    aa_qq_cc    60        NA
```

En este caso, agrupamos por `id` y `unico`, cada nuevo grupo reinicia el calculo, el `data.frame` final quedará en la forma agrupada, pero puedes aplicar `ungroup()` para que retorne un `data.frame` estándar.